# Unable to Create Azure Data Factory Linked Service to Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am attempting to create a Linked Service to Azure Synapse Server using **System-assigned managed identity**

I have configured the System-assigned managed identity, as follows:
[image]

I have added the Managed Identity to the Server and Database as follows:

[image]

[image]

But I keep on getting the error:

[image]

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same scenario in my environment and got the same error as below:**

[image: Ref1]

**Updated**

To solve the error, please follow these steps:

Go to ***Azure Synapse Workspace*** -> ***Azure Active Directory*** -> ***Set Admin*** and go to the Search bar try to find your Managed ***identity name*** or Managed ***identity object*** ,then select and save it.

[image: Ref2]

After that I got the ***access*** and ***connected successfully***.

[image: Ref3]

Comment: Bhanu, thanks for reaching out. I tried your suggestion, however I should point that I'm working on Synapse Server. Also, why would I need to add my client ip address when I want to be able to access the Server from ADF

Comment: Thank you @Patterson for the comment, please check the Update SO thread. Thing is if you are connected to SQL Server need to add client ip address but in your scenario azure synapse client ip address automatically added in Synapse Server no need to add, whenever azure synapse created.

Comment: client ip address mainly used for connecting server to workspace for end-to-end communication purposes. if client ip address properly not added. please add ip address in networking section

Comment: Hi Bhan, as I don't need client ip address added. I needed to authenticate ADF with Synapse

Comment: yes, the above repro scenario working fine for authenticate ADF with Synapse