# Getting error:login failed for user <token- identification principle> data factory linked service to synapse analytics

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to create azure data factory linked service to synapse analytics with system-assigned managed identity but i am getting this error

> Error 22300:Cannot connect to SQL Database:
> @xxxxsql.azuresynapse.net', Database: xxxx, User: Check the linked
> service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database
> firewall allows the integration runtime to access.

Login failed for user token-identified principal

I am getting this error. how solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce same thing in my environment, I got same error.

***To resolve above error, Please follow below steps:***

> Go to **Azure synapse workspace** -> **Azure Active directory** ->
> **Set Admin** -> search for **Azure data factor**, make as admin and save it.

[image: Ref1]

You can **refer** this similar [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72637847/unable-to-create-azure-data-factory-linked-service-to-synapse-analytics/72640680#comment128321558_72640680) thread.